# StackUnify: A community mobile app

Tags: app, placeholder

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

### About

StackUnity intends to allow users of Android and iOS to interact with the StackExchange community.

There is currently a void in multi-subject communities since Reddit killed 3rd party apps. I think there is a great opportunity to create an app that would unify the StackExchange communities and allow users of those communities to more easily interact on their phones.

#### License

What license is your app released under, if any?
No license
Or if it is paid, how much does it cost and how do we buy it?
Not paid at this time

#### Download

Provide links for us to obtain your app.
N/A yet
For websites or services, provide a link to the main or home page.
A user should be able to jump to this section and dive right into your app.

#### Platform

What platform or browser is your app for?
iOS/Android

### Contact

Who created this app? Who are the key contributors?
How do we get in touch with them or find them?

### Code

What language, frameworks, and tools were used to write this?
C#, .NET MAUI
Where can we get the code?
It is not currently hosted anywhere.
How can we contribute to the code?
Currently is no plan